# Facebook Post Call to Action button using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can I add a "Call To Action" for a post using Facebook Graph API? Is it possible or is it free?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: No idea why people are downvoting this question. I would like to do exactly what this question is asking. I'm sure eventually the API will allow the creation of a "Call to Action" button programmatically, instead of the current manual process.

Comment: ^ And after a bit of research, it turns out that the Graph API does allow you to add "Call to Action" buttons to a post. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33559291/1145177).

Comment: If you're trying to add a CTA to a FB page the documentation can be found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/call_to_actions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is explained very well in the official docs: https://www.facebook.com/help/312169205649942

...or in this article: https://www.facebook.com/business/news/call-to-action-button

Afaik there is no way to do this with the Graph API right now.

Edit: My bad, i thought it would be about that call to action button in the Page header. It is definitely possible to programmatically add a call to action button to a Page post, you just need to include a link to the Page post. I´ve tried it in the API Explorer, just replace the Page ID and make sure you are using a Page Token with the `publish_pages` permission:

```
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=POST&path=[PAGE-ID]%2Ffeed&version=v2.5&message=test&link=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.devils-heaven.com&call_to_action={%22type%22%3A%22SHOP_NOW%22%2C%22value%22%3A{%22link%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.devils-heaven.com%22}}
```

It´s specified here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/mobile-app-ads/v2.5#cta_definitions

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this two articles have not use Graph API. I want to add it programmatically using Graph API, is it possible? That was my question.

Comment: added it to my answer. right now it´s not possible.

Comment: The OP is asking about including a "Call to Action" button in a **POST**, not a page header. It is possible to do what the OP is asking. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33559291/1145177).

Answer (score 3):

You can add a "Call to Action" button on posts to Pages (such as fan pages, business pages, etc), but not to personal timelines.

To add a "Call to Action" button to a Page post using the Graph API, simply include the `call_to_action` param:

```
call_to_action={"type":"SHOP_NOW","value":{"link":"http://www.amazon.com"}}
```

A list of available "Call to Action" values are listed on this unrelated page:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/mobile-app-ads/v2.5#cta_definitions

Again, remember the `call_to_action` param only works on Page posts. It will be ignored if you include that param in a post to a personal timeline.

Entire C# code to post to a Facebook page with a "Call to Action" button:

```
string facebookPageID = ""; // a page id needed here. NOT a user id.
string facebookPageAccessToken = ""; // a page access token needed here
string shareLink = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
string url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/"
    + facebookPageID + "/feed?access_token=" + facebookPageAccessToken
    + "&link=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(shareLink)
    + "&message=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("Check this out")
    + "&call_to_action=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("{\"type\":\"SHOP_NOW\",\"value\":{\"link\":\"" + shareLink + "\"}}");
string resp = "";
try
{
    HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    httpRequest.Method = "POST";
    using (HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse())
    {
        using (Stream responsestream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
        {
            if (responsestream != null)
            {
                using (StreamReader bodyreader = new StreamReader(responsestream))
                {
                    resp = bodyreader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    resp = ex.ToString();
}
```

The code above will create this sample post:
[image: Page post with Call to Action button]

Comment: that´s only available for ads afaik, not for standard posts

Comment: @luschn It's available for standard posts, not just ads. We use it when posting to fan pages via the Graph API.

Comment: i´ve tried it yesterday and was not able to create a call to action button. do you have an example post?

Comment: i know that the code would work without an error (you can just try in the api explorer), but i have not been able to get a call to action button to show up, that´s the problem.

Comment: @luschn Just use the code I posted. It creates a sample post with a Call to Action button.

Comment: oh, now it did work with the api explorer, i just needed to add a link to it. it does not work with only a message. makes sense.

Comment: @luschn Please upvote this answer, and the OP's question, so this all becomes more prominent.