# How to create Facebook's app to customize profile picture?

Tags: facebook, customization, photo, facebook-apps, profile-picture

Where do I start if I want to create Facebook app to customize profile picture? I could not find documentation for that.

I see someone made an app to set #starwars themed profile picture. And below, there's a suggestion to customize my own profile photo:
[image: customize profile photo footer]

Clicking `Try it` button, I get such dialog:
[image: facebook customize profile picture]

Anyone knows where it's documented or how to create similar app? Thanks.

*Update:*
Yes I know about Facebook API to get and set profile picture, but I'm interested if there's a way to create these new style apps which opens on top of feed as a dialog? And also how to add these "Try it" buttons in news feed?

Comment: Hey, what's wrong with this question? Tried to google that. Could not find it, but it does not mean, the API is not available.

Answer (score 2):

That´s an official App from Facebook, you can´t create something like that on your own. Of course you can create an App to authorize the User, load his profile picture and change it, but you can´t directly set a new one like in that official App.

There´s probably hundreds of threads about this already, for example:

- [how to set a facebook profile picture using the graph api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306786/how-to-set-a-facebook-profile-picture-using-the-graph-api)
- [Can I set a users profile image using the Facebook API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648859/can-i-set-a-users-profile-image-using-the-facebook-api)
- [Facebook API/PHP - Is it possible to change a user's profile image via FB Graph API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370669/facebook-api-php-is-it-possible-to-change-a-users-profile-image-via-fb-graph)

Either way, the question is WAY too broad for Stackoverflow, you should take the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

> Don't ask about...Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)

About that "try now" button, you could try the suggestions i made in another thread: [Facebook Post Call to Action button using Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30161676/facebook-post-call-to-action-button-using-graph-api)

Comment: Yes I know about Facebook API to get and set profile picture, but I'm interested if there's a way to create these new style `dialog` apps.